# How to share session data between two node.js servers

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have two servers running with Express.js, first one has an active session using Passport.js, I want to send Http request from the second server to the first one to retrieve user data, but the server with the active session always response as there is no session, even though there is an active session

Here is the Passport.js server

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("./config/passport");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const db = require("./models");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({ secret: "keyboard cat", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/user_data", async (req, res)=> {
    if(!req.user) { res.send("No active session") }
    else { res.send(req.user.email)}
})


db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log("Listening on %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", PORT, PORT);
    });
});
```

Here is the second server

```
const express = require('express');

const http = require('http')
const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/user_data',
    method: 'GET'
}

require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const req = http.request(options, res => {
   console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
   res.on('data', d => {
                process.stdout.write(d)
   })
})

req.on('error', error => {
   console.error(error)
})

req.end()
app.listen(PORT);
```

I always get "No active session" response. Even though I have an active session.
Can you please help me with that?

Comment: change the [store adapter](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores), i.e use a database, kv store, otherwise, sessions are stored in the process memory, which is not shared (unless of course you start both servers via forking)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks, that works using express-session-sequelize, it saves the session data in the DB.

Comment: glad to hear it :)